# Trying to run a loop in R to ifelse across enumerated columns

Tags: r

So I have a dataset with variables

```
A_1    B_1     A_2    B_2    A_3    B_3......A_721    B_721
```

I made variable `C_1` using an ifelse statement with `A_1` and `B_1`. Something like:

```
Data$C_1 <- ifelse(A_1 - B_1 <= 365 & A_1 - B_1 >= 0, 1, 0)
```

I want to make this rerun 721 times, to create `C_1` to `C_721` using the respective A and B variables.

All the examples of loops I find online run down a single column, and not across enumerated columns like I want to do here.

I apologize for the simplistic example, but I'm not sure if I can do this using a loop, or apply, or where to start.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. (A useful example doesn't have to have all 721 columns.)

Answer (score -1):

This should work but cannot check without reproducible example

```
        for(i in 1:721)
        {
             assign(paste("C_",i,sep=""),
ifelse(get(paste('A_',i,sep="")) - get(paste('B_',i,sep="")) <= 365 & get(paste('A_',i,sep="")) - get(paste('B_',i,sep="")) >= 0, 1, 0)
    }
```

After this you can just use cbind to attach the C columns to your data

Comment: Thank you! it says "B_" is not found... is there a way to specify which dataset this variable exists in?

Comment: I advise against writing such code in the strongest possible terms. Use lists and data.frames instead. *This is bad code*.

Comment: Try writing get('B_1') and see if it returns value.

Comment: I understand its bad code but without example and more info, it not possible to get a solution which is elegant. Instead of just posting that it's a bad solution, it'd be better if negative reviewers give a better solution.